# mat-table can't bind dataSource

Tags: material-design, angular-material, angular5

I am trying to use angular material table `MatTableModule`, but when passing the data to the `[dataSource]` input I am getting the `Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.` error. I have already imported the MatTableModule and as pointed at GitHub issue #5577 also imported CdkTableModule but still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the material angular version I'm using is v5.2.4, so the template should be `<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource"></mat-table>` instead of `<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource"></table>` according to Angular material v5.2.4 documentation.
https://v5.material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data