# Angular7 - Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular 7.0.2, and I am facing this error while trying to create a table using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

> Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProductionOrderComponent } from './production-order/production-order.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'production-order', component: ProductionOrderComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

html

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="productionOrder" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="t_pdno">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Production Order</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let productionOrder">{{ productionOrder.t_pdno }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="t_mitm">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Item</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let productionOrder">{{ productionOrder.t_mitm }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['t_pdno', 't_mitm']"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['t_pdno', 't_mitm'];"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-production-order',
  templateUrl: './production-order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./production-order.component.scss']
})
export class ProductionOrderComponent implements OnInit {

  public productionOrder

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData()
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/production-order').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res['data'])
      this.productionOrder = res['data']
    })
  }

}
```

What I tried:

- Use `<table mat-table>` instead of `<mat-table>`
- `import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';` in the component

and these links:

[Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228138/cant-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-table)

[mat-table can't bind dataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298241/mat-table-cant-bind-datasource)

Anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You need to `import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';` in the module, not the component, and add `MatTableModule` into the `imports` array

Comment: It is already there. Please see the app-routing.module.ts code section.

Comment: It needs to be in the module where you declare your `ProductionOrderComponent`

Comment: Actually the accepted answer is not right. The problem is that you are using different piece of codes coming from different version of Angular Material. Your HTML code contains <mat-table></mat-table> tags and <th mat-header-cell></th> tags. Solution is choose a version and stick to it. <table mat-table></table> with <th mat-header-cell></th> and <td mat-cell></td> or newer version <mat-table></mat-table> <mat-header-cell></mat-header-cell> <mat-cell></mat-cell>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should import `MatTableModule` in `AppModule` or in the Module where you component is declared.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatTableModule
    ...
  ]
})
public class AppModule
```

or

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatTableModule
    ...
  ],
  declarations : [ProductionOrderComponent]
})
public class MyModule
```

Comment: Not working for me as well. Tried in Angular 7. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @Uttam - You must be using this in other module, make sure you are importing `MatTableModule` into that module.

Comment: Using a SharedModule where I imported MatTableModule but forgot to export it. Whoops!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to complete Sunil's answer: you should import `MatTableModule` and `CdkTableModule`in `AppModule` or in the Module where you component is declared.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatTableModule
    ...
  ]
})
public class AppModule
```

Comment: Worked for me. Add import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table'; as mentioned here: https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/api#CdkTable I however don't know why this is required....

Answer (score 2):

If you think you did everything right by importing *MatTableModule* at app.module.ts like below

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    CdkTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and changing *< table >* to < meta-table > at html and it is still not working than have a look how you write your *dataSource* property tag.

> it  has to be [dataSource] not [datasource]